# Forecast time series with ARIMA doesn't seem to take into account end of activity

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, statsmodels, forecasting

I have different time series `ts_values` turned to list and I want to predict the next itemss using an ARIMA model but it seems not to take care about zeroes:

```
row['shop_id']:  5  row['item_id']:  5037
[2599.0, 2599.0, 3998.0, 3998.0, 1299.0, 1499.0, 1499.0, 2997.5, 749.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
predicted: 2599.019975890905
-------------------
row['shop_id']:  5  row['item_id']:  5320
predicted: 0
-------------------
row['shop_id']:  5  row['item_id']:  5233
[2697.0, 1198.0, 599.0, 2997.0, 1199.0, 0.0]
predicted: 2697.000099353263
-------------------
row['shop_id']:  5  row['item_id']:  5232
predicted: 0
-------------------
row['shop_id']:  5  row['item_id']:  5268
predicted: 0
-------------------
row['shop_id']:  5  row['item_id']:  5039
[5198.0, 6597.0, 2599.0, 5197.0, 749.5, 1499.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
predicted: 5198.0926378541535
```

So I wondered what did I did wrong there.

Here is my code:

```
  import statsmodels.tsa.arima.model as smt

  ranges = range(1, 5)
  for difference in ranges:
      # try:
      tmp_model = smt.ARIMA(ts_values, order=(0, 1, 0), trend='t').fit()
      tmp_aic = tmp_model.aic
      if tmp_aic < best_aic:
          best_aic = tmp_aic
          best_difference = difference
          best_model = tmp_model
          # except Exception as e:
          #     print(e)
          #     continue
  if best_model is not None:
      y_hat = best_model.forecast()[0]
```

I know `difference` is of no use there. It was used for the coefficient of ARIMA. But I've been told that as far as my lists would be of a max size of 32 I should use a simple time forecasting (0,1,0).

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: version 0.12.2 of Statsmodels has been released, so your original code should now work.

---

Unfortunately, this is a known bug with `ARIMA` in v0.12.1. Until v0.12.2 is released, one option is to use `SARIMAX` instead:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.statespace import sarimax as smt

...

tmp_model = smt.SARIMAX(ts_values, order=(0, 1, 0), trend='t').fit()
```